# Get information of the 3G router Wireless Sim Card

Tags: c#, wifi, 3g

I want to know if it's possible to detect informationsuch as IMSI, MSISDN of my Sim card that exist inside of my 3G router Wifi such as  *http://www.4gltemall.com/huawei-b970b-3g-wireless-router.html* with C#
I have made my homework and lot of search nut no result, please any help I will be very happy.

Answer (score 0):

The high level interface you are looking for (router <-> laptop) is defined by the manufacturer and isn't publically available.  The device's own on-board software has 3G-specific information.

EDIT:
This device is a mobile wifi hotspot that plugs into a computer.  To connect the hotspot to the internet, it also contains a 3G modem.

Usually, it has some on-board software that is displayed on the computer, typically in a browser when you plug it in.

Because this device gives you an internet connection, you can get Windows internet data like the IP addresses from System.Network.NetworkInformation.
Details about the 3G modem are not part of Windows internet data - they are lower level, and normally you must get them from another, lower level interface like Windows Mobile Broadband API.

However, in this case, there is no direct interface between the 3G modem on the "outside" interface of the wifi router, and the computer.  This 3G modem doesn't expose a modem port in Windows, neither does it appear on the computer as a mobile broadband network adapter.  It only has interfaces inside the wifi router.  Typically, it will have an interface to the on-board software, which will show information about the device and SIM.

Therefore, if you want to get information about the 3G part of the wifi router, you are dependent upon what the device manufacturer chooses to tell you.  Maybe the manufacturer has implemented a proprietary interface between the router and the computer that lets the computer get some information about the 3G device and SIM.  But this is not part of any standard, and also it is not needed by Windows.

To convince yourself that the router doesn't show a network adapter that you can use with Windows Mobile Broadband API, try the following:
 When you plug the device in, it shows as a CD-ROM in Windows Device Manager.  After you have converted it, using the manufacturer's own converting tool, it shows as a Network Adapter.  If it was a modem, you would be able to get 3G device information over this Network Adapter.
However, if you type, at the cmd prompt "netsh mbn show interfaces" and the Network Adapter of the router does not show up.  This means, that it's not an mbn interface, therefore you can't get 3G information over Microsoft's Windows Mobile Broadband API.

EDIT2:
To open Windows Device Manager, first open Windows Explorer, and right click on "Computer".  Choose "Properties".  In the left hand bar of the properties windows, click on the option "Device Manager".
Here, you'll see all the hardware components that are present in the system. If you plug in the wireless router, you'll first see it as a DVD/CD-ROM drive.  When it converts itself, you should see it appear under Network Adapters.
You won't see it under Modems, because it doesn't expose a modem interface to the computer.

Now go to Start | Run, and type "cmd" to open the DOS box.  Type "netsh" to start the netsh program, and then "mbn" to enter the MBN context (mobile broadband).  Now type "show interfaces" and netsh mbn will show you all the mobile broadband interfaces in the system.
At this point, if you have a normal modem plugged in, you will see it here.  The wireless router won't be visible, because it doesn't expose a mobile broadband interface.

Netsh overview documentation is [here.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754753%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)
The netsh "mbn" context is available if you have the netsh helper dll, wwancfg.dll on your computer (I think it is included as part of Windows professional editions, I have never had a problem with it not being there.)
Type ? at the netsh mbn> prompts to get a list of available commands.  More meaningful documentation is a bit hard to find, but the commands are fairly obvious.

Comment: thanks for your response,I want to do that with C#, how can I detect and retrieve the SIM information such as IMSI or MSISDN, or how can I detect information on wireless network such as CellID or LAC , thank you

Comment: You can't, because the interface for this information isn't available.  Ask the manufacturer if they will make the interface public.

Comment: Ok thank you, please another question, it's possible to get out the CellID of my router wireless network in C# ? because I did this task but i was able just to get the network Id, network Name, Data Speed, network description from " using System.Net.NetworkInformation".

Comment: Cell Id (of the 3G network cell) is also not possible in my experience. Only with the manufacturer's own interface.

Comment: can you please explain more to me

Comment: I added some more explanation above.  Hope that makes it a bit clearer.  Try investigating the device in Windows Device manager, and at the cmd prompt with netsh.

Comment: Hi can you please explain more how can I do the test, because I can't do it myself

Comment: Thank you very  much for your response. it's very helpful

Comment: So can you please give me some sort of solution to this issue! how can I  and what have to do to obtain the Cell ID of my 3G router Wifi ! 
-> I have to communicate with the manufacturer (huawei) to allows me accede to my 3G router wifi information ???

Comment: Yes. There is no other way to get information about the 3G part of the device.

Comment: ok thanks, please I want to ask you a question, the stackoverflow web site has stopped me to ask a question, did you know any way to resolve the issue. or can you please  vote for this question ?

Comment: Well, I understood your question, but it is a little off topic and that's why it was closed.  Without testing, I think Hans Passant is correct, and you can't use these AT commands while you're connected.  You could get the information you need via Windows Mobile Broadband API (google it).  If you can't use Mobile Broadband API (for example because your device doesn't expose a network adapter) then I think Passant is correct, and it's not possible.

Comment: so how can I re-ask a question ! I search in the Internet how to resolve this issue but no idea

Comment: To re-ask the question: make it very clear, and don't forget to say that you are talking about an inherited connection.  Do paragraphs, to make the question more readable.  Tag it with GSM, UMTS, Telecommunications tags, not C# - it isn't really a C# question.  You can't find this kind of specific answer in the internet mostly - you need to read the reference material yourself, and do a lot of tests, then you are able to answer these questions yourself (that's what being an engineer is about :-) )

Comment: Yes I see, so the Problem now is when I want to ask a new question the system appear the following message:"Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See http://goo.gl/C1Kwu to learn more.", how can I resolve this!

Comment: Follow that link, and read *everything* on the page. It will tell you everything.  I know it's not so easy when you aren't a native english speaker, but hey, there is a reason why engineers get paid a lot!  Good luck.

Comment: Yes :) I'm with you, i'm also a Moroccan engineer, that why my English is a little tired. thank you

Comment: just a question please, can I get the Manufacturer name of may Router Wifi under c# ? !!